# xpath (//a[contains(., "Test-Test-P24-FA")]) fails to select

Tags: xpath

This is what I have

```
<a href="/1005523" class="managed_account_link being_setup" target="_self" title="Being Setup" style="background-color: transparent;">1005523 Test-Test-P24-FAID-EUR</a>
```

I want to write an XPath for the `a` based on its contained text. I tried the below but it does not work

```
xpath=(//a[contains(., "Test-Test-P24-FA")])
```

However, when I try this one, it works.

```
xpath=(//a[contains(., "Test-Test-P24-FAI")])
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest do you suggest I restart everything and try again?

Comment: `//a[contains(., "Test-Test-P24-FA")]` works fine and returns DOM Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of this below mentioned `xpath`.

```
//a[contains(., 'Test-Test-P24-FAID')]
```

> OR

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Test-Test-P24-FAID-EUR')]
```

> OR

```
//a[text()='1005523 Test-Test-P24-FAID-EUR']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
//a[@class='managed_account_link being_setup'][text()='1005523 Test-Test-P24-FAID-EUR']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute and `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
//a[@style='background-color: transparent;'][text()='1005523 Test-Test-P24-FAID-EUR']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `style` attribute and `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hoever I want to search via -P24- and whenever I remove the 1005523, it does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I noticed that if I remove the 1005523, it stops.
edit: I also noticed that xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'1005523 Test-Test-P24-')])[2] works but I want to be able to remove this 1005523

Comment: But all the above mentioned `xpath` that i given to you is working for me without showing any error.

Comment: Wait why do you use indexing number at the end of the xpath `[2]`?

Comment: Please put question with proper information, then only it will be easy for those who are trying to helping you. provide relevant information.

Comment: I am using selenium IDE to find a specific text and then click on it via xpath. This is an internal option for selenium (right click on the tag and it goes directly to selenium) and this is what it has given me. Not sure what the [2] means, but if I remove it it stops working.